# List of properties of an object

Tags: delphi

How can I get a list of properties (at Run-time) of an Object which is not a Component. Like a Grid Cell which has it's own properties (Font, Align, etc).

Grids like AdvStringGrid or AliGrid, or Bergs NxGrid.

Answer (score 10):

What you are asking for requires accessing the object's RTTI (Runtime Type Information).

If you are using Delphi 2009 or earlier, only published properties and published methods (ie, event handlers) are exposed by RTTI.  Look at the [`GetPropInfos()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TypInfo.GetPropInfos) or [`GetPropList()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TypInfo.GetPropList) functions in the [`System.TypInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TypInfo) unit.  They provide you with an array of pointers to [`TPropInfo`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.TypInfo.TPropInfo) records, one for each property. `TPropInfo` has a `Name` member (amongst other things).

```
uses
  TypInfo;

var
  PropList: PPropList;
  PropCount, I: Integer;
begin
  PropCount := GetPropList(SomeObject, PropList);
  try
    for I := 0 to PropCount-1 do
    begin
      // use PropList[I]^ as needed...
      ShowMessage(PropList[I].Name);
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(PropList);
  end;
end;
```

Note that this kind of RTTI is only available for classes that derive from `TPersistent`, or have the [`{M+}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Run-Time_Type_Information_(Delphi)) compiler directive applied (which `TPersistent` does).

If you are using Delphi 2010 or later, all properties, methods, and data members are exposed by *Extended* RTTI, regardless of their visibility.  Look at the [`TRttiContext`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Rtti.TRttiContext) record, and [`TRttiType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType) and [`TRttiProperty`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Rtti.TRttiProperty) classes, in the [`System.Rtti`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Rtti) unit.  Refer to Embarcadero's documentation for more details: [Working with RTTI](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Working_with_RTTI_Index).

```
uses
  System.Rtti;

var
  Ctx: TRttiContext;
  Typ: TRttiType;
  Prop: TRttiProperty;
begin
  Typ := Ctx.GetType(SomeObject.ClassType);
  for Prop in Typ.GetProperties do
  begin
    // use Prop as needed...
    ShowMessage(Prop.Name);
  end;
  for Prop in Typ.GetIndexedProperties do
  begin
    // use Prop as needed...
    ShowMessage(Prop.Name);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: there is no reason for creating the TRttiContext. I initializes it self when you start use it

Comment: I am using D7. The above code only works if SomeObject is a Component.

Comment: Actually, it works for any object that derives from `TPersistent`, or has the [`{$M+}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Run-Time_Type_Information_(Delphi)) directive applied to it (which `TPersistent` does).